# 404 page on Route not working as expected with children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I have a user route with two children.
I used `path="*"` in the case where the url does not match with a user so that it then returns UserNotFoundPage.

The problem is, while it does give me UserNotFoundPage when the url is `.../user/someIncorrectUsername` , it gives me an empty page if I only enter `.../user/` or `.../user` . While I would have expected it to get me to the UserNotFoundPage.

How can I get this behavior ?

Here is my code:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    {/* PUBLIC */}
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/welcome"/>}/>
    <Route path="/welcome" element={<HomePage/>}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardPage/>}/>
    {/* RESTRICTED */}
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage/>}/>
    {/* PRIVATE */}
    <Route path="/user" element={<Users/>}>
      <Route path="*" element={<UserNotFoundPage/>}/>
      <Route path="username" element={<UserProfilePage/>}>
    </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>

function useAuth() {
  return true;
}

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

function UserNotFoundPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>User not found</p>
    </div>
  )
}

function Users() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return auth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login"/>;
}

function UserProfilePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>USER PROFILE PAGE</h4>
    </div>
  )
}

function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Login page
      </h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that abstractly "/user" also represents a route path that can be matched and rendered, via the `Outlet`, but there is no content to render on an *exactly* matched "/user" path.

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. *If the parent route **matched exactly**, it will
> render a child index route **or nothing if there is no index route**.*

You can specify the `UserNotFoundPage` route to ***be*** the route that matches and renders on "/user" as well as on any non-matched "/user/*" path by specifying it to be the index route.

```
<Route path="/user" element={<Users/>}>
  <Route index path="*" element={<UserNotFoundPage/>}/>
  <Route path="username" element={<UserProfilePage/>}>
</Route>
```